# neo4j javascript/nodejs driver not calling onCompleted or onError

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, driver

I have a basic NodeJS/Neo4j setup that seems to be working just fine, however I have noticed that *driver.onCompleted* and *driver.onError* are not called as I expected, based on the documentation here in the **Usage Examples** section:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver

My setup looks like this:

```
'use strict';
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
const authConfig = require('../keys/authConfig');

//Set up connection driver
let driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost',  neo4j.auth.basic(authConfig.neo4jAuth.username, authConfig.neo4jAuth.password), {
    trust: "TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE",
    encrypted:"ENCRYPTION_NON_LOCAL"
});

driver.onCompleted = function(){
    console.log('DB Driver Connected');
};

driver.onError = function($err){
    console.log('DB Driver Error: ', $err);
};
```

Now mind you everything runs fine, I am able to make calls to the db etc., but I would have expected either of those callbacks to be called.
I assume I'm missing something trivial.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I misunderstood the purpose of the onCompleted and onError callbacks.

I had assumed those would be called during initial driver setup and connection to DB.

It seems that this assumption is incorrect.  Those are in fact called but only after an attempt to setup a session.

So they are not called during initial setup, but subsequent session calls.

Comment: I was hitting the same confusing results that you described in your initial post. Thank you for your follow up!